# Como definir carateres a usar na criação de um salt

Tags: c#, criptografia

Preciso de gerar um salt, mas preciso que todos os carateres façam parte de uma lista de numeros e letras.

```
string usedChars  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

Gero o salt com esta função:

```
public static byte[] GenerateSalt(int SaltByteLength)
    {
        System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rncCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] salt = new byte[SaltByteLength];
        rncCsp.GetBytes(salt);

        return salt;
    }
```

É possível alterar a função para indicar os carateres a usar?

Comment: Por que limitar o `salt`? Ou por outra, você não poderia usar um randômico de bytes para uso nas senhas e sua representação em base64 para armazenar e transportar?